# How to handle thumbnail images on a product listing website where the user uploads the image

Tags: php, html, image, thumbnails, image-uploading

We have the following code that allows our admin user to upload images to the directory $folder:

```
        echo ' <form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ';
        echo ' File: <input type="file" name="filename" />';
        echo ' <input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
        echo ' </form>';

        $folder = "/home/imageupload/images/";
        if (is_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))
        {  
                    if (move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['name'])) 
            {
                echo "File uploaded: " . $HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['name'];
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            Echo "File is not uploaded.";
        }
```

This image that they upload will later be associated to an item (Via the user) and at this time, we would need a thumbnail version of the image to display, as well as the full size image to appear in the lightbox.

**How can i auto generate a smaller copy of the uploaded image upon upload for a thumbnail, and also account for portrait and landscape images, as both need different size thumbnails?**
In the past i noticed that just resizing the original image using html would slow down the website as the image is still huge (ex image-height=100px, image-width=80px).

Answer (score 1):

There are free php scripts that do this well:

1. http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/website-thumbnail-generator.php (We've tested, easy)
2. http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ (we have not tested)

You can download it and adapt it to your usage.... A big time consuming job...

Comment: What do you mean a big time consuming job? haha

Comment: One day or more of programming / ajusting.

Comment: Sounds terrible.  I would rather resize hundreds of image by hand in photoshop than do that.

Comment: If you have photoshop, run batch handling automatically 1000's photos itself... There is no better soft than Photoshop CS4/CS5,... It's the best way as you save your apache server resource...

Comment: Fair enough.  I will check out the links you listed above. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 1):

Go to this link:

http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1304

Its simple, easy to understand and security was also considered for image upload in the above link. It wont take more than 20 minutes to understand and deploy the code :). Complete code is also given at the bottom.